# Unit Tests code duplication?

Tags: testing, unit-testing, code-smell

How can I avoid code duplication in unit tests?

Using Java and JUnit suppose I have something like this:

```
public interface Arithmetic<T> {
    public T add(T a, T b);
    public T sub(T a, T b);
}

public void IntegerArithmetic<Integer> {
    //
}

public void DoubleArithmetic<Double> {
    //
}
```

And the test class:

```
public class TestArith {

private Arithmetic<Integer> arith;

@Before
public void init() {
    Arithmetic<Integer> arith = new IntegerArithmetic();
    Integer term1 = 4;
    Integer term2 = 3;
}

@Test
public void testAdd() {
     assertEquals(7, arith.add(term1, term2));
}

@Test
public void testAdd() {
     assertEquals(1, arith.sub(term1, term2));
}
}
```

The problem is that the test class for the DoubleArithmetic class should look exactly the same; the only difference is in @Before init() where the initialization of the concrete type is done. How can this code duplication be avoided?

Comment: I think this question is a much better fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129693/is-duplicated-code-more-tolerable-in-unit-tests

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not necessarily, if we're talking about designing the unit test class.

Comment: It should be noted that doubles will not necessarily be _exactly_ equal, so you may have differences due to that.  The `assertEquals(double, double)` method is deprecated, after all (use the one with an epsilon instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare class TestArith as abstract. Then create two classes, TestIntegerArith and TestDoubleArith extending TestArith. In the TestArith create an abstract method getArithmetic, which returns an instance of Arithmetic. Then change the tests to get Arithmetic instance by calling getArithmetic.

So it would look like this:

```
public abstract class TestArith<T> {
  protected abstract Arithmetic<T> getArithmetic();

  @Test
  public void testAdd() {
      assertEquals(7, getArithmetic().add(term1, term2));
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you have many testMethods you can call getArithmetic from the setUp method and assign the arithmetic to an instance property. I just learned this technique at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbSqXFUfRMU&feature=youtu.be&t=1960 from a talk by Sebastian Bergmann, author of PHPUnit

Answer (score 1):

This is not always so.

Obviously, tests for `10 / 4` or `1 << 31 * 5` will give different results in `IntegerArithmetic` and `DoubleArithmetic`.

If there's a large subset where `IntegerArithmetic` and `DoubleArithmetic` should act the same, try instantiating a class based on a common interface, e.g. `Arithmetic<java.lang.Number>`.

Let me elaborate a bit.

There are two places where code duplication may arise: the initialization, which only differs by the class being tested, and the test cases.

Common tests can go into a common case which can be subclassed, and each subclass's `.setUp()` will instantiate its own concrete instance of `Arithmetic` to test.

Class-specific tests get their own test cases.

Initialization code can be de-duplicated by using a parametrized base class from which concrete instances of `TestCase` will arise, as @Skillwired proposes.

Comment: The expected value may differ, but the logic of the code is identical; the code is identical. Regarding the second idea, that's the problem: both classes need to be tested so both need to be instantiated for this.

Comment: See the updated answer.